# Elasticsearch returns total 624 but hits array is empty

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this query with a strange result: it returns a total of 612 documents but no hits.

This is the query:

```
{
  "from": 900,
  "size": 30,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "user_id": "145698489"
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "date_created": {
                        "to": "2016-07-30T20:11:09.176-03:00",
                        "gte": "2016-07-07T23:39:45.530-03:00"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "resource.object.label": "hidden"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "should": []
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the result:

```
{
    "_shards": {
        "failed": 0,
        "successful": 1,
        "total": 1
    },
    "hits": {
        "hits": [],
        "max_score": 1,
        "total": 612
    },
    "timed_out": false,
    "took": 73
}
```

But if I change the date ranges I get the results correctly.

Why ES is doing this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because you set `from` to `900`. If you have less than `900` hits it won't return hits.

Answer (score 2):

in my case this happened because i set the limit to zero, lol.

Comment: Welcome! This is not really an answer to the question. Please read this on [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this is a fine answer to the question. It could easily help someone who does the same in the future

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set from :0.in your query.
Also important to know, is that there were some changes to ES recently about how it handles scrolling. Hence the spot where you should put scrol is important, try to set one `next_scroll = results['_scroll_id']` out side while loop and the other scroll `next_scroll = results['_scroll_id']` at the end of your while loop code line. After i have changed the scrol spot it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

We also hit this, and to resolve it we needed to remove the `excludes` cluase from the `_source`

```
_source: {
  excludes: %w{embedding score tags}
},
```